# Cannot get API response to show on map

Tags: geojson, openlayers-6

I have an openlayers application where I have an empty layer like this loaded into my map:

```
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer, Image as ImageLayer, Group} from 'ol/layer';
import {Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';

var isolayer = new VectorLayer({
  title: 'isolayer',
  style: new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(121, 131, 242, 0.6)',
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#1420a3',
      width: 1,
    }),
  }),
});
```

Later I have an API call that reponds with a GeoJSON feature collection called body. This feature collection contains a single isochrone polygon.
I then try to input this feature collection into a source and append that source onto my layer.
Going by my console logs it seems like the features get read into my source but when i put my source onto my layer they dont follow.

```
var isosource = new VectorSource({
      features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(body)
    });
    console.log('features loaded in are ', isosource.getFeatures());
    isolayer.setSource(null);
    isolayer.setSource(isosource);
    console.log('source for isolayer is', isolayer.getSource());
  });
```

Here I would have supplied an image of my console log but as this is not allowed:

features loaded in are
0: Feature
values_:
center: (2) [11.757829851595691, 55.23061102982857]
geometry: Polygon {disposed: false, eventTarget_: und etc.

source for isolayer is
VectorSource {disposed: false, eventTarget_: undefined, pendingRemovals_: null, dispatching_: null, listeners_: {…}, …}
featuresCollection_: null
ol_uid: "248"

Theres more to the log but im not sure anything else is relevant.

Does anyone know why the feature in the polygon seemingly doesnt carry over? Or why it does not appear on my map.

Answer (score 0):

The features need to be read into the view projection

```
features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(body, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', FeatureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()})
```

Comment: This changed the features of the source and it now loads in an array of features instead of just the center which I guess is good.

But it still does not appear on the map.

Comment: Is there a problem that im doing the isolayer.setSource() inside a function? Do I need to somehow call the isolayer var as a window?

Comment: How are you layers added to the map?  Your isolayer may be obscured by another layer.

Comment: They are in a group like this
`
  new Group({
    title: 'Data',
    layers: [
      grid100km,
      grid30km,
      //grid1km,
      universities,
      isolayer,
      municipalities,
      hospitals,
      schools,
      leisureparks,
      //cities,
      dk_boundary
    ]
  })
];
`
With a map like this
var map = new Map({
  controls: defaultControls().extend([scaleline, geocoder, layerSwitcher, new FullScreen()]),
  layers: layers,
  view: mapView,
  target: 'map'
});